# Elasticsearch _bulk update issue giving VersionConflictEngineException message

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch in one of my project. I am facing an issue while updating a record. The error message that I am getting is:-

```
{ _index: 'makes',
  _type: 'make',
  _id: '55b8cdbae36236490d00002a',
  status: 409,
  error: 'VersionConflictEngineException[[makes][0] [make][55b8cdbae36236490d00002a]: version conflict, current [168], provided [167]]' }
```

Using ES bulk api. My application is in node.js.

Let me share my code too:-

```
var conditions = [];
    conditions.push({
        update: {
            _index: config.elasticSearch.index,
            _type: config.elasticSearch.type,
            _id: id
        }
    });
    conditions.push({
        doc: {
            published: true
        }
    });
    client.bulk({
                    body: conditions
                }, function(err, resp) {
                    console.log(resp);
                    console.log(resp.items[0].update);
                     return res.send({success: true, message: "Shows updated successful"})
                });
```

The below is the value of conditions array:

```
[ { update: 
     { _index: 'makes',
       _type: 'make',
       _id: '55b8cdbae36236490d00002a' } },
  { doc: { published: true } } ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you start querying a record, its response with the record including the version of that record. When you want to update it, but before it, it has been updated by another, the record in the database has a higher version than what the client thinks. 
This may happen because some operation are still in queue, so you get the unprocessed record (hence lower version). When this happens, try https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/indices-refresh.html:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/{your_index}/_refresh'
```

Then call your method again

Comment: Some problems appear impossible to fix, unless you've encountered them before... It had cost me hours :p

Comment: Yes, You are right. You saved my day. It was our project release and this issue came.

Comment: Go fix the rest of the release then ;-)

Comment: I will to that. Do we have any method to add timeout in make.report. I am using makeapi-client for creating updating and deleting record from Elasticsearch.?

Comment: I don't use node.js, nor make.report (I'm using the Java API), so that would be a (really) wild guess, which I have to Google then. I think you might be better off Googling that yourself

Comment: Ok no problem. Thanks for the great help :) I accepted (y)

Comment: Refresh manually is a costly operation so is it right approach to deal with it?